# GAE Python - Some performance settings must be changed via Module configuration files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, gae-module

I've migrated my app to using modules instead of backends. To do so, I followed the instructions on this page: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

For some reason however, when I go to the App Engine Dashboard and then to Administration > Application Settings, the following notification is shown under Performace:

```
Some performance settings must be changed via Module configuration files. See the Modules documentation for more information
```

With the notification there is a link included which leads to the page I posted above.

The top of my app.yaml looks as follows (and therefore should take default settings):

```
application: myapp
version: uno
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
```

And the top of my module looks as follows:

```
application: myapp
module: tasks
version: uno
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
instance_class: B4
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

What performance settings is the notification referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to the scaling options under Configuration on the modules documentation page you've linked to.

If you don't have modules (or rather just have one, with the default auto-scaling using just app.yaml) then the Application Settings page has sliders you can use to control the instance-class, the max- and min-pending-latency and the min- and max-idle-instances. For multiple modules, you need to put this configuration in the yaml files - as you've done for your tasks module. (You can potentially have lots of modules - having sliders for each of them would make that page very confusing.)

When it says "must be changed", it doesn't mean that you *must* make changes, just that if you *do* want to make changes, you have to do it via the yaml files and not via that page.